# C# WPF How to keep Application responsive while adding many UI Elements to Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, ui-thread

I made an Application where I add many Grids to some Stackpanels in a for loop. My problem is that, while the for loop is loading my Application doesn´t respond and my Loadinganimation is freezed. How can I add the Grids to the Stackpanel without affecting the UI Thread, so my Loading Animation won´t freeze.

Thanks in Advance

Edit:

Grid creation Method:

```
        public void GridExample()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
            {
                Grid Grid1 = new Grid();
                Grid1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                Grid1.Width = 200;
                Grid1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)33, (byte)33, (byte)33));
                Grid1.Margin = new Thickness(5, 20, 5, 20);

                ColumnDefinition Grid1_col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                Grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(Grid1_col1);

                RowDefinition Grid1_row1 = new RowDefinition();
                RowDefinition Grid1_row2 = new RowDefinition();
                RowDefinition Grid1_row3 = new RowDefinition();
                RowDefinition Grid1_row4 = new RowDefinition();
                Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(Grid1_row1);
                Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(Grid1_row2);
                Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(Grid1_row3);
                Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(Grid1_row4);

                Grid1_row1.Height = new GridLength(255);
                Grid1_row2.Height = new GridLength(60);
                Grid1_row3.Height = new GridLength(5);
                Grid1_row4.Height = new GridLength(55);


                //Adds Grid to HomePage
                homepage1_mainstackpanel1.Children.Add(Grid1);

                Image Image1 = new Image();
                Image1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Image.png"));
                Grid.SetRow(Image1, 0);
                Grid1.Children.Add(Image1);


                Label Label1 = new Label();
                Label1.Content = "Example Text";
                Label1.FontSize = 15;
                Label1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                Label1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                Label1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                Grid.SetRow(Label1, 1);
                Grid1.Children.Add(Label1);


                Line Line1 = new Line();
                Line1.X1 = 1;
                Line1.StrokeThickness = 2;
                Line1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)51, (byte)51, (byte)51));
                Line1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                Grid.SetRow(Line1, 2);
                Grid1.Children.Add(Line1);


                Button Button1 = new Button();
                Button1.Content = "Play";
                Button1.FontSize = 15;
                Button1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                Button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)33, (byte)33, (byte)33));
                Button1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                Button1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                Button1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                Button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
                {
                    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new WatchPage1());
                });
                Grid1.Children.Add(Button1);

            }
        }
```

Loading Animation in HomePage:

```
public static Dispatcher mainthread_dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        public HomePage1()
        {
            Loaded += Page_loaded;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (LoadingAnimation loadanimation = new LoadingAnimation(GridExample))
            {
                loadanimation.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

LoadingAnimation.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Spaceflix_Desktop.LoadingAnimation"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Spaceflix_Desktop"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="110" Width="90" Loaded="Animation_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#B25B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="#B25B5B5B"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#7F5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse3">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#B25B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse4">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#7F5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse5">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#B25B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse6">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#7F5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse7">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#B25B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse8">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7F5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#005B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="sc#0, 0.104616486, 0.104616486, 0.104616486"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="#7F5B5B5B"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

   
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>


        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="#c62828" BorderThickness="2" Background="Black" Height="80" Width="80">
            <Grid x:Name="maingrid" Background="Transparent">
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse2" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0, 15, 15, 0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse3" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse4" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0, 0, 15, 15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse5" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse6" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15, 0, 0, 15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse7" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse8" Fill="#FF5B5B5B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15, 15, 0, 0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

</Window>
```

LoadingAnimation.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace Test_Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für LoadingAnimation.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class LoadingAnimation : Window, IDisposable
    {
        public Action Worker { get; set; }

        public LoadingAnimation (Action worker)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Worker = worker ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        public void Animation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }).ContinueWith(t => HomePage1.mainthread_dispatcher.Invoke(() => Worker()), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).ContinueWith(t => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Close()));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this Information are enough

Comment: Have you tried using a VirtualizingStackPanel?

Comment: Run the creation scripts in a separate task, then when they are done, update the layout with the new elements.

Comment: @spzvtbg That advice doesn't make much sense, because all elements in a common visual tree have to be created in the same thread.

Comment: How is the loading animation implemented?

Comment: @Clemens May be OP can create all in a new page and than put it into frame in a mainpage

Comment: @spzvtbg No.....

Comment: We need some reproducible example in the question. Can you make some and add to the question? Or at least add some code that illustrates the issue. Possibly the solution is easy but with currect given information i cannot answer, can't suggest but only can guess. Thus, the question in current state isn't suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Clemens I added the Information

Comment: @Jason I tried it with a VirtualizingStackPanel based on the Example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel?view=netcore-3.1 but the UI is still frozen while the Grids are loaded in the Stackpanels.

Comment: 120 simple grids. It's not a complicated UI. Simply refactor your code to MVVM. Replace StackPanel with ListView or ItemsControl, and it'll render in milliseconds.

Comment: Also, if you're going to add really many grids that way, you may rich a (very high) limit of panel's children, while there is practically none for ItemsControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I didn't have time for this project for a long time, I've now dealt with it again and found a solution. I can't add the grids to the stack panels in a new task or thread but at least I can display the loading animation smoothly. Because the grids have to be added to the main thread, I ran the loading animation in a new thread. So I had to display it as a popup. This is the best solution I found.

Here is the Code from the HomePage:

```
        var PositionWindow = (Window)Parent;
        int CenterX = 8;
        int CenterY = 1;
        Point CenterPoints = new Point(PositionWindow.Left + CenterX + (PositionWindow.Width / 2), PositionWindow.Top + CenterY + (PositionWindow.Height / 2));

        Thread LoadThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
            using (PopUpLoadingAnimation loadanimation = new PopUpLoadingAnimation(GridExample, CenterPoints, PositionWindow))
            {
                loadanimation.StartTask();
                Dispatcher.Run();
            }
        }));
        LoadThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        LoadThread.Start();
```

I had to calculate the middle of the Window by myself to make the PopUp centered.

And here is the Code of the PopUpLoadingAnimation.cs:

```
public partial class PopUpLoadingAnimation : Popup
{
    public Action Worker { get; set; }
    private Point _PlacementPoints { get; set; }
    private Window MainWindow { get; set; }


    public PopUpLoadingAnimation (Action worker, Point PlacementPoints, Window mainthreadwindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Worker = worker ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        MainWindow = mainthreadwindow;
        _PlacementPoints = PlacementPoints;
    }

    public void StartTask()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
        {
            Storyboard animationboard = Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard;
            animationboard.Begin(maingrid);

            LoadingPopup.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
            LoadingPopup.HorizontalOffset = _PlacementPoints.X;
            LoadingPopup.VerticalOffset = _PlacementPoints.Y;
            LoadingPopup.IsOpen = true;

            HomePage1.mainthread_dispatcher.Invoke(() => MainWindow.IsEnabled = false);

        })).ContinueWith(t => HomePage1.mainthread_dispatcher.Invoke(() => Worker()), HomePage1.mainthread_scheduler).ContinueWith(t => Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => 
        {
            LoadingPopup.IsOpen = false;
            HomePage1.mainthread_dispatcher.Invoke(() => MainWindow.IsEnabled = true);
            Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown(); 
        }));
    }
```

by the way thanks for the answers, unfortunately they did not help